# Imgur ID match using Regex in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, imgur

I am pretty inexperienced when it comes to regular expressions and wondered if anyone can help me achieve the following.

I need a regular expression that will validate if a certain URL is a valid imgur image and return the ID of the image.

```
 Match imgurMatch = imgurRegex.Match(URL);
 if(imgurMatch.Success)
    id = imgurMatch.Groups[0].Value
```

Here are some examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uGCs.jpg (ID = qtPdb)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/skRRh.jpg (ID = RcVIa)

(Could be of type .jpg, .png, .gif)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o0jW.jpg (ID = 3ZZuG)

I think a regular expression that can handle the above and return the correct ID would be good enough for me, since even if validation fails for some reason, I will be able to handle it in another way.

Please let me know if any more details is needed.

Thanks!

Tribe84

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Regex imgurRegex=new Regex(@"http://(?:i\.imgur\.com/(?<id>.*?)\.(?:jpg|png|gif)|imgur\.com/(?:gallery/)?(?<id>.*))$");
Match imgurMatch = imgurRegex.Match(URL);
if(imgurMatch.Success)
   id = imgurMatch.Groups["id"].Value
```

Comment: Note imgur also hosts PNG and GIF images, so the test for the .jpg part should be made to account for that generically.

Comment: ahh I don't know the url format I was just matching your question, now updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Bob, how as stated above, how would I change that it can handle PNG or GIF images too? I will award you the answer regardless.

Comment: Answer now handles extra file types

Comment: Great! Thanks, I have edited my question to include the other file types and awarded you the answer!

Comment: Make sure that you account for the lesser-used 'jpeg' format. Exactly the same as 'jpg', just a pain in the ass sometimes ;)